# Stuck Call to undefined function oci_connect() using XAMPP

Tags: php, oracle, web, xampp, oracle12c

i'm want connect PHP to Oracle Database 12c, i'm already try in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJme5JMxKeo

- i'm already install xampp v3.2.2 and using PHP 5.6
- install oracle database 12c :
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html
- test login in SQLPlus 
  [image]
- unzip and paste Instant Client(Version 12.1.0.2.0) 
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html
  to directory C
- set path environtment **C:\instantclient_12_1;**
- uncoment semicolon (;) **extension=php_oci8_12c.dll** in php.ini
  [image]
- and already download php_oci8_12c.dll file in here : http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.0.8/windows

  and already paste to in **C:\xampp\php\ext**
- when i test script connect : http://pastebin.com/f1isKKar
  [image]

error message : Call to undefined function oci_connect()

i'm confused why can't connect to ORACLE DATABASE 12c :(

Comment: tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27775963/1426539

Comment: @yivi not working

Answer (score 8):

you are very close.

1. Add oci.dll, oraociei12.dll, and oraons.dll from C:\instantclient_12_1 to xampp/apache/bin folder. Replace the existing ones.
2. Restart the Apache

N.B: Make sure that your PATH environment variable are set to this folder "C:\instantclient_12_1".

Comment: Awesome, this should be an accepted answer, no one mentioned placing these DLLs in the apache/bin

Answer (score 2):

Check whether command line PHP works.  See if there are any log errors.  Make sure you have the right [OCI8 DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40843827/4799035). Triple check you have 32bit Oracle Instant Client and that it occurs first in PATH. If you have other Oracle libraries installed then your webserver may be finding them first: fix this.

Answer (score 0):

i have the exact same problem and fix it in the php.ini file by uncommenting this

`extension_dir = "./"` "remove semicolon"